# IE7 / 8 Not adding css attribute 'top' as an inline style dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on some code that someone else has put together. The idea is that on one page you have multiple tables on the page. To start with they are only just an image on but when you click into the image you can view the whole table. The tables are wrapped in a div overlay which controls the positioning of the table depending where you are on the page.

The script basically find where you are on the page and then will add the 'top' attribute as an inline style and the pixels will depends on which table you click on and where you are on the page. It works fine in all browsers but IE7 / 8.

I've worked out the problem is, it's not added the 'top' attribute as an inline style. In IE7 / 8. I tried added a class where the top can be added in there but the styles can't be added dynamicaly that way.

Anyway here is some code:

Snippet of the JS that adds the top attribute:

```
// Get the current browser size and scroll position
        viewport_width = viewport().width;
        viewport_height = viewport().height;

        viewport_offsetx = window.pageXOffset;
        viewport_offsety = window.pageYOffset;


        $("#tablesorter_overlay").css("top", viewport_offsety);



        table_instance = $("#tablesorter_" + $(this).attr("rel"));
        table_instance.css("position", "absolute");


        // Make a copy of this table so we'll have the original safe, and set it to be sorted. Add it to the overlay
        new_table_instance = table_instance.clone().tablesorter();
        new_table_instance.appendTo("#tablesorter_overlay");
        new_table_instance.show();
```

//Table & overlay HTML after the table has been clicked on...

```
<div id="tablesorter_overlay" style="top: 2803px;" class="topclass">
<p class="tablesorter_overlay_close"><a href="#">X</a></p><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablesorter generic" id="tablesorter_2" style="max-width: 95%; position: absolute;">
<thead> 
<tr> etc..
```

**NOTE: The html code is the firefox code, it's the same in IE but without the 'top' attribute.

I know there is a lack of code but i'm hoping you won't need anymore as ive (fingers crossed) found the problem.

Thanks!

Josh

***ANSWER****

```
function getScrollTop(){
        if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        //most browsers
        return pageYOffset;
    }
        else{
            var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
            var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
            D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
            return D.scrollTop;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Josh, welcome to SO. It seems that you have found a solution to your problem on your own. In this case, SO encourages you to post the solution as an answer and accept it so that people ending up at this page because they've encountered the same problem have a solution at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting position:relative on its parent.

Answer (score 0):

function getScrollTop()

```
{
        if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
        //most browsers
        return pageYOffset;
    }
        else{
            var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
            var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
            D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
            return D.scrollTop;
    }
    }
```